# The conversion from datetime to INTEGER is unsupported

Tags: java, datetime

I'm getting an Exception

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from datetime to INTEGER is unsupported.

My code is

```js
public int[][] beam_CurrentStatus() {
  int arr[][] = new int[1][31];
  int i = 0;
  try

  {
    con = getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 c.logtime, a.BL1_data_SS_ST,a.BL2_data_SS_ST,a.BL3_data_SS_ST,a.BL4_data_SS_ST,a.BL5_data_SS_ST,a.BL6_data_SS_ST,a.BL7_data_SS_ST,a.BL8_data_SS_ST,a.BL9_data_SS_ST,a.BL10_data_SS_ST,a.BL11_data_SS_ST, a.BL12_data_SS_ST,a.BL13_data_SS_ST,a.BL14_data_SS_ST,a.BL15_data_SS_ST,a.BL16_data_SS_ST,a.BL17_data_SS_ST,a.BL18_data_SS_ST,a.BL19_data_SS_ST,a.BL20_data_SS_ST,a.BL21_data_SS_ST,a.BL22_data_SS_ST,a.BL23_data_SS_ST,a.BL24_data_SS_ST,a.BL25_data_SS_ST,a.BL26_data_SS_ST,a.BL27_data_SS_ST,b.st1_prmt_status_p45,c.beam_current,c.beam_energy from INDUS2_BLFE.dbo.main_BLFE_status a inner join INDUS2_MSIS.dbo.main_MSIS_status b on a.logtime=b.logtime inner join INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT c on b.logtime=c.logtime ORDER BY c.logtime DESC ";

    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {
      for (int j = 1; j < 31; j++) {
        if ((rs.getInt(j)) == 1)

          arr[i][j] = rs.getInt(j + 1);

      }


    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException in  Bean " + e);
  } finally {
    closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
  }

  return arr;


}
```

Moreover ,the output is coming as

> [[I@1783d33

How to resolve the issues.

Comment: Try to use rs.getDate(j), where j is a datetime column.

Answer (score 0):

The database field datetime is not mapped to integer automatically. You should use the rs.getDate() method, which returns a java.sql.Date object. This object you can convert to long (not int) representing the milliseconds since 1970-01-01 at 0:00

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested you should use `rs.getDate()` method

> Moreover ,the output is coming as [[I@1783d33

In Java any array is a subclass of *Object* which has the following implementation of *toString()* method:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

You need to convert your array to String manually. For one-dimensional arrays you can use the `java.util.Arrays.toString(int[])` method

Comment: how to do it in two dimensional array.Moreover I'm not using any field whose data type is of datetime type